# Is this injective projection map open?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let X be a locally closed algebraic sub variety of $\mathbb C^{m+n}$. Let $p: \mathbb C^{m+n}\to \mathbb C^{m}$ be the projection map. Suppose that the restriction of p to X is injective. Is the map $p: X \to p(X)$ open in Euclidean topology? Note that p(X) is Zariski constructible in $\mathbb C^{m}$.

Comment: [Crossposted at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366318/is-the-restriction-of-a-projection-map-open). In general, you should wait much longer than 43 minutes before cross-posting, and you ought to link all versions of your post together.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this in mind.